# Django custom login page

Tags: python, django, validation, authentication

I have a custom Django login page. I want to throw an exception when username or password fields are empty. How can I do that?

My view.py log in method :

```
def user_login(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Gather the username and password provided by the user.
        # This information is obtained from the login form.
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        print("auth",str(authenticate(username=username, password=password)))

        if user:
            # Is the account active? It could have been disabled.
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        else:
            return HttpResponse("xxx.")
    else:
        # Bad login details were provided. So we can't log the user in.
        print ("Invalid login details: {0}, {1}".format(username, password))
        return HttpResponse("Invalid login details supplied.")
    else:
        return render_to_response('user/profile.html', {}, context)
```

I tried this and it didn't work:
This is forms.py

```
def clean_username(self):
    username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
    if not username:
        raise forms.ValidationError('username does not exist.')
```

Comment: Can you please update the question with the correct indentation

Comment: just define `clean_username(self): if not self.cleaned_data['username']: ValidationError('')` method in corresponding form.

Comment: Hi, I put it just for testing, xxx is a html site.

Comment: The suggested solution is to use frontend javascript to check when the login button is pressed.

Comment: Hi, it didn't work. It still redirect to xxx html site although fields are empty.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use login view, which is provided by Django. So your login.html should look like that example.

```
<form class="login" method="POST" action="/login/">

  {% csrf_token %}

  {{form.as_p}}

  <li><input type="submit" class="logBut" value="Log in"/></li>
  </form>
```

And remember urls.py !

```
url(r'^login/$','django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name': '/login.html'}),
```

Comment: I didn't have form.as_p.

Comment: This answer is no longer valid, in newer django versions you need to use:
`from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView`
`urlpatterns.append(url(r'^login/$', LoginView.as_view(template_name='login.html'), name="login"))`

Comment: How is this to look like for Django 3?

Answer (score 6):

The correct approach is to use [forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/), instead of fetching the variables directly from `request.POST`. Django will then validate the form data, and display errors when the form is rendered in the template. If a form field is required, then Django will automatically display an error when the field is empty, you don't even need to write a `clean_<field_name>` method for this.

Django already has a [built in login view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#all-authentication-views). The easiest approach is to use this rather than writing your own. If you still want to write your own view, you will still find it useful to look at how Django does it.

Comment: I don't understand why everybody wants to use the built in login view so much? Sorry for reviving an old thread, but is there an easy way I am missing as to how you would alter this view? As in, add classes to input elements and other attributes?

Comment: You say *I don't understand why everybody wants to use the built in login view so much*. I look at it the other way - I don't see why you would want to write your own view which might have bugs or even worse security flaws, when there is a well tested, widely used view included in Django.

Comment: @Zeretil I can't help with adding classes to input elements, that's off topic for this question. I would guess that question has been answered elsewhere on Stack Overflow already, and if you can't find it, then it's better to start a new question rather than asking in the comments.

Comment: Because, @Alasdair, the built-in view is very minimalistic, and nobody would put such an ugly login page on their website in production I would hope.

And don't worry, I managed to implement it myself by creating a custom form. I'm quite sure the functionality is the same as the Django login view, but it just looks better (using MDL).

Comment: The built in view has always allowed you to specify which form to use. As of Django 1.11 it is class based, so it is even easier to customize. You shouldn't need to use a custom view to change the way it looks. The built in view doesn't come with a template, so it is neither ugly or beautiful. There's a real danger of introducing security flaws with a custom login view, which is why I discourage it on Stack Overflow.