# Create login page without using Django default login form

Tags: python, django

I would like to know if it’s possible to create his own login page (from scratch) without using any Django default login forms because I want to add other fields in addition?

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Looks like it is possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35773576/django-custom-login-page)

Comment: In that code, he used "authenticate" with user = authenticate(username=username, password=password) which is native to Django and is located in "from django.contrib.auth" and it only takes 2 parameters (username, password). But in my case, I want to add more fields for the authentification

Comment: Yes you can, but why? save your self the headache and work with what django offered you for free. what exactly do you want to add?

Comment: login using djngo rest framework or using template?

Comment: login using django without its native authentification system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write your own view, but it's better to just subclass the Django [LoginView](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/3.0/django.contrib.auth.views/LoginView/) and change as much as you need, for example:

```py
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView
from django.contrib.auth import login
from .forms import MyCustomLoginForm

class SignInView(LoginView):
    form_class = MyCustomLoginForm
    template_name = 'path/to/my_template.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # Form is valid, do whatever you need.
        login(self.request, form.get_user())
        response = HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
        return response
```

forms.py

```py
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm

class MyCustomLoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    age = forms.IntegerField(label='Age', required=True)

    def clean_age(self):
        age = self.cleaned_data['age']
        # validate age
        return age
```

Comment: It's a good idea but is it possible to have on that page something like : username, password and age?
Thx

Comment: @hitech My suggestion is you subclass the ``AuthenticationForm`` and add the extra fields you required and validate the data on the same form. I updated my answer to give you an idea.

Answer (score 1):

in this user model, I have declared username field as email. User can't get login using username and password. User have to provide email and password to get login.

my models.py

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None, active=True, is_staff=False, is_admin=False,is_superuser=False):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Users must have an email address")
        if not password:
            raise ValueError("Users must have password")
    user_obj = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email)
        )
        user_obj.set_password(password)
        user_obj.staff = is_staff
        user_obj.admin = is_admin
        user_obj.active = active
        user_obj.superuser = is_superuser
        user_obj.save(using=self._db)
        return user_obj

    def create_superuser(self, email, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(
        email,
        password=password,
        is_superuser=True,
        is_staff=True,
        is_admin=True,
        )
        return user


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
    objects = UserManager()
    def _str_(self):
        return self.email

@property
def is_staff(self):
    return self.staff

@property
def is_superuser(self):
    return self.superuser
```

my views.py

```
from .models import User
class LoginAPIView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = LoginSerializers(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            data = serializer.data
            email = data['email']
            password = data['password']
            user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
                return Response({"message": "success", "code": status.HTTP_201_CREATED, "details": serializer.data,
                             "Token": token.key})
            return Response(
                {"message": "error", "code": status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED, "details": ["Invalid credentials"]})
```

my serializers.py:

```
class LoginSerializers(serializers.Serializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(max_length=255)
    password = serializers.CharField(max_length=128)
```

may be this could help you

Comment: Thx @Merin, but it still uses "django.contrib.auth.models". I want to know if it's possible create login page without using that

Comment: you could override that user model